# sendKeys() in Selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to *Selenium*. I just want to send keys to a username text box and send a tab key both at a time so that text box can check for availability of username.

Here is the code:

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='User Name:']/following::div/input")).sendKeys("UserName");
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='User Name:']/following::div/input")).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```

But this one is not working.

Comment: Do you want to send both Keys at the same time or have a delay then Tab? Also Is the Tab command working on its own (With out the "UserName been entered)?

Comment: It should enter username first then hit TAB key.

Comment: You may just have to add a slight wait command between the two actions. Can you see Selenium entering the Text for the User Name?

Comment: Your method works for me. Also, you can do `driver.findElement(By.xpath("...")).sendKeys("UserName" + Keys.TAB);` or even `driver.findElement(By.xpath("...")).sendKeys("UserName", Keys.TAB);`. All of these work for me.

Comment: @Lt_Shade I do see selenium entering the text for User Name. I have tried by adding wait in between.

Comment: You could try using sendKeys("\t"); but it doubt that would do much

Comment: Also what browser are you using?

Comment: @Lt_Shade I am using firefox 24v

Comment: According to the bottom of http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions some browsers which support synthetic events (firefox) act differently when using the Tab Key.  `When a user presses the 'tab' key the focus jumps from the current element to the next element. This is done by the browser. With synthetic events the browser does not know that the 'tab' key is pressed and therefore won't change the focus. With native events the browser will behave as expected.`

Comment: Also Native events can be turned on and off in Firefox using `FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);`. Not sure if this is your problem but it might be worth investigating

Comment: @Lt_Shade tried with `profile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);` still not working :(

Comment: It might just be time to use a click out or Enter until someone else can provide a solution sadly.

Comment: Related: [python - Send keys not to element but in general selenium - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28482297/send-keys-not-to-element-but-in-general-selenium#comment115981598_28482297) (although that question is for Python)

Answer (score 18):

I doubt for `Keys.TAB` in `sendKeys` method... if you want to use TAB you need to do something like below:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.keyDown(Keys.TAB).perform()
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a single line command to send the TAB key;

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Enter_ID")).sendKeys("\t");
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe Selenium now uses `Key.TAB` instead of `Keys.TAB`.

Comment: As of Selenium v3.141, the class is still `Keys`.

Comment: strange @MichaelBerry, I  wasn't able to get it to work unless I used Key

Answer (score 1):

> For python selenium,

Importing the library,

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

Use this code to press any key you want,

```
Anyelement.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

You can find all the key names by searching this `selenium.webdriver.common.keys`.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that creating a var to hold the `WebElement` and the call the `sendKeys()` works for me.

```
WebElement speedCurrentCell = driver.findElement(By.id("Speed_current"));
speedCurrentCell.sendKeys("1300");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Robot` class in java for pressing TAB key. Use the below code.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='User Name:']/following::div/input")).sendKeys("UserName");

Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
```

Comment: is there any other way than using robot?

Comment: You can just click on the next available element after entering username. `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='User Name:']/following::div/input")).sendKeys("UserName");` `driver.findElement(By.xpath("next element in webpage")).click();`

Comment: I tried that too but it sometimes works and sometime it won't

Comment: Are you waiting for sometime, for the message (username available) to appear ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
WebElement userName = pathfinderdriver.switchTo().activeElement();
userName.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your code. It will make the answer better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will surely work:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='User Name:']/following::div/input")).sendKeys("UserName" + Keys.TAB);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, and then import the package:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='username']")).sendKeys("username");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='username']")).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Password']")).sendKeys("password");
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays it can be done as such, when posted via Flask from localhost:

```
chrome_path = 'chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")

driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://gibiru.com/")

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.form-control.has-feedback.has-clear').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.form-control.has-feedback.has-clear').send_keys("lfc")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.form-control.has-feedback.has-clear').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
List<WebElement>itemNames = wd.findElements(By.cssSelector("a strong")); 
System.out.println("No items in Catalog page: " + itemNames.size());
   for (WebElement itemName:itemNames)
    {  
       System.out.println(itemName.getText());
    }
```

Comment: Post a description above the code please, so others can understand what you did

Answer (score -2):

The simplest solution is Go to Build Path > Configure Build Path > Java Compiler and then select the 'Compiler compliance level:' to the latest one from 1.4 (probably you have this).