# Send keys not to element but in general selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Issue:

I want to `send_keys(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL + 't')`
Now to do this I locate any element on the page

```
elem = self.browser.find_element_by_name('body')
elem.send_keys(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL + 't')
```

Problem is that each time I want to send above keys I have to locate some element, which actually I'm not interested in.

How can I send keys generally and not to specific object of page, I want something like `self.browser.send_keys(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL + 't')`? Is it even possible?

Comment: Probably anyname is not unique for the target element

Comment: If the target is a text box anyway, you might want to send to it directly: [java - In Selenium how do I find the "Current" object - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491806/in-selenium-how-do-i-find-the-current-object)

Answer (score 38):

You are using WebDriver to interact with the actual elements on the page. It will not work.

Try using the Actions

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL + 't')
actions.perform()
```

See the documentation:
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=send_keys#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains