# How to scroll within an internal scroll menu on a page? Python/selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Tryin to scroll through a scroll box within a page, the html code looks like this:

```
<main data-infinite-scroll-context="" id="chat" data-chat-initialized="true" data-chat-current-filter="inbox" class="flex-auto h-100 overflow-auto"></main>
```

So far I have tried:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
htmlElem = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="flex-auto h-100 overflow-auto""]')
htmlElem.send_keys(Keys.END)
print(i)
time.sleep(2)
```

and:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    htmlElem = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
    htmlElem.send_keys(Keys.END)
    print(i)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Neither of which are leading to the desired result. Would appreciate some help if possible.

Comment: Sending keys to browser itself might work, check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/28482440/12422518

Comment: I have previously tried that as well, it won't work. The scroll box is embedded.

Comment: How about execute JS scroll https://stackoverflow.com/a/44540150/12422518

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem 2 years ago, problem was the selection of the field to send keys. Solution for me was a action chain.

```
        actions = webdriver.ActionChains(self.driver)
        actions.move_to_element(body_element)
        actions.click()
        for x in range(scroll_count):
            actions.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
            actions.wait(1)

        actions.perform()
```